# What color I see objects with a green glass in a room lightened by red light?

Tags: visible-light, vision

Suppose the only light source in a room is red light.
What would see an observer with a green eyeglasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the green eyeglasses only let green light pass through them, since they are transparent. Therefore if the only source of light was red light, then the entire room would be in darkness if viewed through the eyeglasses.

The phenomenon displayed by your theoretical glasses is in fact the reason that the old (anaglyph) 3D glasses worked. One plastic lens only let red light pass through, and the other blue. The image you saw through the glasses was a composite of a red and blue image formed when one eye saw only the blue image and one eye the red. If they are appropriately spaced images, then the brain will process these two 2 dimensional images and make it appear three dimensional, as it does when we see in everyday life.

Additional info after comment by DJohnM:
This assumes the 'red' light being emitted and the frequencies of 'green' light being allowed through do not overlap in their frequency spectra. I say this because the cells in our eyes that independently sense red, green and blue light can sometimes overlap in their sensing abilities meaning they can 'see' (be stimulated to send electrical signals to the brain) parts of the frequency spectra of the other colours of light. This is in fact, when pronounced enough, a cause of colour-blindness.

Comment: Irrespective of any overlap in retinal cell sensitivity, if there is no overlap in the wavelengths of light in the **red** light, and the wavelengths transmitted by the **green** glasses, then there would be total darkness.  Say, a red laser and a green region narrow bandpass filter...

Comment: @DJohnM that is a good point - I should have probably highlighted that it was the light passing through that should not overlap in frequency spectra

Comment: In Europe they still use pure sodium vapor lamps for street lights. Sodium lamps with no phosphors emit a very narrow spectrum consisting of two frequencies, both in the yellow part of the spectrum.  When I visited there, at night the visual appearance was an eerie monochrome. The most striking feature was that bright red doors on houses appeared pitch black, since they reflected none of the yellow light.